# MacVim - CTRL+C only exits insert mode after arrow key press

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, vim, macvim

Before today, CTRL+C would exit insert mode in MacVim just fine. As of today, when I press CTRL+C, nothing happens until I press an arrow key. Only then does it exit insert mode. If I press some other key, it stays in insert mode and types that key.

This is all I have in my .vimrc file:

```
set number
syntax on
colorscheme industry

" filetype plugin indent on
set tabstop=4
set expandtab

" Disable dragging with the mouse
" Use shift+click to select
noremap <LeftDrag> <LeftMouse>
noremap! <LeftDrag> <LeftMouse>
```

Is there some setting I may have accidentally changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's you, Ctrl-C seems to have broken.

This may be the problem: https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/846

Comment: I note that the problem has been quickly addressed, and Ctrl-C works just fine now!